# Properly call mocha done callback and promises

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have several integration tests in my app:

```
 it('creating vehicle', function (done) {
    createVehicle()         
      .then(() => {
        done();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        done(err);
      });
  });
```

`createVehicle` makes post request and returns promise:

```
 return request.json('post', '/api/vehicle/')
    .send(obj)
    .expect(200)
    .then((res) => {
      expect(res.body).toExist("Body is empty");
      expect(res.body.id).toExist("Id is empty");     
      return res.body;
    });
```

Now all works fine, but if I rewrite first snippet in the following way:

```
it('creating vehicle', function (done) {
        createVehicle()         
          .then(done) //*
          .catch(done); //*
      });
```

I get error from Mocha

> done() invoked with non-Error

I understand why. The `createVehicle` return `res.body` and it's passed to `then` callback, in result `done` run as `done(arg)` and I get the error, because mocha `done` callback has to be called without arg when there is no error and with argument when there is error.

Is it possible to use this variant:

```
 .then(done) 
 .catch(done);
```

How to achieve this?

Of course, I can delete return statement, but `createVehicle` is used in several places and I need returned value:

```
it('creating vehicle with media', function (done) {
    createVehicle()
       .then(createMedia)  //createMedia will get returned value       
      //....
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just return the promise instead of having to deal with callbacks, because Mocha [supports promises out-of-the-box](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises):

```
it('creating vehicle', function() {
  return createVehicle();
});
```